# How can i get records such that my input is array of ids and collection field just id using mongodb aggregate

Tags: mongodb

Input : "program_id": `["5e995225a9cdc44ffc335bb5","5eb3e9e03edcda4db73c2ba8","5e99522fa9cdc44ffc335bb6"]`

how can i match with "program" field in below collection

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5eddcaa6783db57d44ffd188"),
        "name" : "Dennis",
        "program" : ObjectId("5e995225a9cdc44ffc335bb5"),
        "deleted" : false,
        "__v" : 0,
        "updated_date" : ISODate("2020-06-08T05:21:35.221Z")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

with `$in`

Remember: Your array of ids should be ObjectIDs

```
db.collection.findOne({ program: {
   $in: array
}})
```

Comment: I think, this will not work, because the `array` will be array of strings, not array of `ObjectId`s as per the OP.

Comment: @ngShravil.py yes, i wanted to mention that but somehow i forgot it

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the `program` `ObjectId`s to strings and then use `$in` operator.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      program_str: {
        $toString: "$program"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      program_str: {
        $in: [
          "5e995225a9cdc44ffc335bb5",
          "5eb3e9e03edcda4db73c2ba8",
          "5e99522fa9cdc44ffc335bb6"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      program_str: 0
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayGroundLink](https://mongoplayground.net/p/-qDnHOHf4Kt)

More shorter version of the above query:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $in: [
          {
            $toString: "$program"
          },
          [
            "5e995225a9cdc44ffc335bb5",
            "5eb3e9e03edcda4db73c2ba8",
            "5e99522fa9cdc44ffc335bb6"
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayGroundLink](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Z1E_iNWhG_o)

Comment: how can i give req.body,program_id in query and how can i get match records from different collections at a time collection names like mentor parent and child

Comment: You should replace the array with `program_id`.